# Remove item from PHP arrays

Tags: php, arrays

How can I remove certain items of an array?

Let's say I have an array with 10 elements, I want to remove elements at index 0, 3, and 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) supports removing individual array elements. The order of the remaining elements isn't affected.

```
unset($array[0], $array[3], $array[8]);
```

To reindex the array, simply call [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on it. Order is still maintained until you call a sorting function on it; this just reindexes:

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I reindex the array?

Answer (score 0):

[`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) will remove any number of consecutive elements, starting at either end.

It will also re-index your array, and has an option to not re-index.